# gvim script not working properly with delete

Tags: vim

```
function! Reduce()
    let ls=getpos("'<")
    let lsp=ls[1]
    let tvar = '\<' . @*
    echom tvar

    for i in range(1,30)
      let ssv=getline(lsp+i-1) 
      let t1=matchstr(ssv,tvar)
      echom t1
      if t1 =~ @*
        echom ssv
        delete
      endif
    endfor
endfun
```

can you please help me with the above script?
what is the problem with this script..
if i removes the if condition and simply print the ssv. it prints all 30 strings with the match
but when i put the delete command - it only does the match for few strings.
tried and verified same behaviour with "normal! dd" in place of "delete" command as well.

Answer (score 2):

You use `getline` in a `for` loop with `i` as the relative line number. And you delete lines in the loop. What's happening here is:

```
line1
line2 <- i = 2
line3
line4
```

You delete line2:

```
line1
line3 <- i = 2
line4
```

Then `for` loop increases `i`:

```
line1
line3
line4 <- i = 3
```

so the next processed line is `line4`, not `line3` as you expect.

To solve that delete lines from the end to the start, i.e. run `range` in reverse direction:

```
for i in range(30, 1, -1)
```

Answer (score 1):

As phd said, you need to reverse the direction of your iteration.

For performances reasons, I tend to prefer to avoid for loops here. If you had thousands of lines (I know, you only have 30...), you'd have perceived a difference.

I would write it this way (in case I need something more complex than `:delete`):

```
" untested
let first_line = line("'<")
" 1- extract all lines in the range
let lines= getline( first_line, first_line+30) " or 29 ?
" 2- convert lines into line numbers, or -1 if not matching
let matching_line_nrs = map(lines, 'match(v:val, tvar)>=0 ? v:key : -1')
" 3- keep the positive ones
call filter(matching_line_nrs, 'v:val > 0')
" 4- and finally remove the matching lines, in reserve order
" NB: I though there was a deleteline() function, but couldn't find any
" trace of it, hence execute(linenr.'delete')
call map(reverse(matching_line_nrs), 'execute(v:val."delete")')
```

Which is quite convoluted when compared with the native (and extremely efficient)

```
:exe "'<".',+29g/\<'.@*.'/d'
```

Or, when typed interactively

```
 :'<,+29g/\<^R*/d_
 " With ^R being CTRL-R
```